# Duende Identity Server- Why I get an error ArgumentNullException after accepting consents (only on deployed .Net 6)?

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I have a project that uses Identityserver 4 with Blazor server. With .Net 5, it worked like a charm, both on development and when deployed. I updated to .Net 6 and Duende Identity server. After updating the project, it works on development, but I get this error after I accept the consents the and Idp server redirects to my application.
"ArgumentNullException: IDX10000: The parameter 'json' cannot be a 'null' or an empty object. (Parameter 'json')
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage..ctor(string json)"
System.ArgumentNullException: IDX10000: The parameter 'json' cannot be a 'null' or an empty object. (Parameter 'json')
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage..ctor(String json)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)

I have spent days on this issue, but could not end with a solution. I appreciate a lot if anybody can help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In ISS, I set the Application pool identity to "localSystem" for the site running IDP, and it is running now.